# GStreamer Get Exact Time of 1st Frame

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I'm running GStreamer from the command line to record video to H.264 avi like this.

```
gst-launch tvsrc fps-n=25 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, framerate=(fraction)25/1' ! vpuenc codec=6 ! avimux ! queue2 max-size-buffer=1 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! filesink location=output.avi
```

There is some init time from when I do gst-launch till when the video actually starts recording.

Is there any method to get the exact time of the very 1st frame output to text file? Or better still, the exact time of every frame? 
Thank you.

Comment: You can define `GST_DEBUG=filesink:6` and `GST_DEBUG_FILE=<path>` variables to get log output to a file - it will be enough to get exact time of every frame (you will probably get a lot of information you don't need so you will have to filter through it, also keep in mind that this method may impact overall performance significantly)

Comment: @kaman thanks. Is there a way to just get the 1st frame, though? Since you'll be printing to file every frame I think you are right that it willl impact overall performance. Running on an arm chip here so I need to take care of that.

Comment: @kaman I got the log, what should I look for to find the 1st frame? It is as you said, a lot of info. Is the timestamp where the last "set to PLAYING" occurs sufficient?

Comment: The log you pointed is filesink changing it's state to `PLAYING`. If you want fairly accurate timestamp when buffer is written to the file you should look for something like `writing xx bytes at`. You can also cut the number of logs by setting the same level of debugging in `GST_DEBUG`  as log message you are interested about (6 is getting all messages).

Comment: Thanks so much @kaman , by this reasoning, the last writing xx bytes at will give me the timestamp of the last frame, right? And I can do a minus-ing of the timestamp of the last frame from the timestamp of the 1st frame to get the actual video duration, and hence * by the fps to get the actual number of frames? Pls do correct me if I am wrong, thanks!

Comment: The last timestamp - the first timestamp should give you quite accurate video duration. If by actual number of frames you mean all frames in the video you are rught